# Object.create(Object.prototype) vs var task=Object.create(Object)

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

while creating a new object, why do we use

var task=Object.create(Object.prototype);
              instead of ,
var task=Object.create(Object);

Comment: They are different objects with different members. It depends on what you want. For `Object.create(Object.prototype)` why not just write `{}`?

Comment: Well because `Object.prototype !== Object`. Did you inspect them to tell the difference?

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks .looking at console i knew they are  different objects . but i wondering if anyone can demonstrate different scenarios when each of them are preferred

Comment: @Bergi thanks .looking at console i knew they are  different objects . but i wondering if anyone can demonstrate different scenarios when each of them are preferred

Comment: @Bikash We almost never need an object that inherits from the `Object` constructor function, that's why we don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

In [MDN Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), there are two examples:

`const me = Object.create(person)`

`Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)`

I combined them into one sample:

```
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.speak = function() {
    console.log("this is an instance function")
  }
}
// Shape.speak = ...

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('this is a prototype function');
};

function Rectangle() { Shape.call(this); }
function Triangle() { Shape.call(this); }

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape);

var rect = new Rectangle();
var tri = new Triangle();

rect.constructor // f Shape
tri.constructor // f Function

rect.speak // f speak
tri.speak // f speak

rect.move // f move
tri.move // undefined, could not access methods in Shape.prototype
```

The result of `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)` is `rect.__proto__.__proto__  ===  Shape.prototype`

The result of `Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape)` is `tri.__proto__.__proto__ === Shape`

To understand this, we have to understand the core of [Object.create() Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill)

```
Object.create = function (proto, propertiesObject) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = proto;

  // (new F()).__proto__ === F.prototype === proto
  return new F(); 
};
```

Which derived to：

```
(new F()).__proto__ === F.prototype === Shape.prototype
Rectangle.prototype === new F()
rect.__proto__.__proto__ === Rectangle.prototype.__proto__  === (new F()).__proto__ === Shape.prototype

(new F()).__proto__ === F.prototype === Shape
Triangle.prototype === new F()
tri.__proto__.__proto__ === (Triangle.prototype).__proto__ === (new F()).__proto__ === Shape
```